# Tomcat- Servlet not printing everything

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I have below code which is used to print entered username and password while doing a BASIC authentication but some how its not printing it, when i tried to run it locally after modifying the code as a java program it works. Below is the ouput in browser after successful authentication.

[image: Output Snapshot]

Also below is the Servlet code which i used.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("This is the Test Servlet");

        Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
            out.print("<br/>Header Name: <em>" + headerName);
            String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
            out.print("</em>, Header Value: <em>" + headerValue);
            out.println("</em>");
        }
        out.println("<hr/>");
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("authorization");
        out.println("User and Password in Base64 encoding--------------------------->>>" + authHeader);
        //String encodedValue = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
        String encodedValue = authHeader;
        //byte arr[] = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedValue);
        byte[] asBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedValue);
        out.println(new String(asBytes, "utf-8")); 
        out.println("Not printing ????");
        out.println("</em>");
    }

}
```

Comment: even for a test, try not having any html in your controller

Comment: Try adding `out.close()` at end.

Comment: @ Rahul Yadav it didn't work out.close()

Comment: What do the logs say? I'm betting your code is throwing an exception and you just aren't looking at the logs.

Comment: @Christopher Schultz, awesome you got it correctly, exception was "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [TestServlet] in context with path [/securityTest] threw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20" Now its working Thanks. Can you post it as answer so that i can accept?

Comment: I've added an answer for completeness, and add a little explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have an error in your servlet that is causing execution to stop short.

The reason you don't see a nice error message in the browser window is because your servlet has produced enough output to fill the internal response buffer, and so the buffer has been flushed, "committing" the response (that's a semi-technical term, at least as far as the servlet spec is concerned).

Once the response has been "committed" (that is, the first byte has been sent to the client), you can't change the response status code, any headers, etc. so there's no way to tell the client that something broke, other than to wreck the page output itself.

It's always best to look at the logs when things start acting funny.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is triggered on this line:

```
out.println(new String(asBytes, "utf-8"));
```

because there is not such constructor for String. You probably meant to use [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)):

```
out.println(new String(asBytes,  Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: I modified as per your inputs  to out.println(new String(asBytes,  Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); still not working

Comment: `String.<init>(byte[],String)` certainly does exist. It's been there since Java 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close and flush the out object.

```
out.close();
out.flush();
```

I hope this will print output on screen.

Comment: That should be the other way around, first `flush` then `close`.

Comment: @Aravind Chavhan It didn't work , out.flush(); and out.close();